# Терминал в кодировке UTF-8 не отображает кириллицу из переменной

Tags: c++, utf-8, кириллица

Русский язык у меня в коде работает, литровые строки выводятся, русские слова в переменных тоже. Но при вводе русского слова в переменную через cin на выводе онo не отображается, то есть вообще ничего нету, ни в cmd ни в windows powershell работает только в Windows terminal(cmd или powershell). Код в кодировке UTF-8, терминалы тоже. Если сменить кодировку в терминале на 1251 то кириллица из word отображается а из word2 превращается в кракозябры.

```
int main()
{
    std::string word, word2 = "Пупкин";
    std::cin >> word;
    std::string word3 = word + " " + word2;
    std::cout << word3;
    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте добавить файл заголовка

```
#include <Windows.h>
```

а в мейне добавить

```
 SetConsoleCP(1251);
 SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
```

если не работает попробуйте вписать в мейн

```
setlocale(LC_ALL,"ru");
```

Comment: Это работает, для вводимой переменной. Но инициализированная превращается в кракозябры.

Comment: и то и другое? Если да, то странно очень. Какие инклюды у вас есть? Какая ос?

Comment: Странно что в терминалах cmd и powershell у меня не отображается русское слово которое я ввожу через cin. Но в эмуляторе терминалов Windows terminal все нормально. Ну и все работает если я код сделаю в кодировке 1251 и терминал тоже в кодировке 1251.

Comment: Инклуды iostream и string. Windows 10.